# how to get the name of subcollection in cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have database (Like the image below) and I Need to get the name of subcollection which contain Quiz Name

[image]

Comment: There are no any way to do that.

Comment: Collections are like table name. You need to know their names, you should not have any random collections

Comment: thank you all, can I make  document inside document in cloud firestore?

Comment: Nope, but you can extend your query and make regular nested collection where you know its name and documents inside there.

Comment: Or you can just dump all quizzes in one collection and group it using some special keywords, so you can query for those special quizzes you need.

Comment: Like `{ category: "math", level: "basic" ....}` You will be able to query all math quizzes and can sort them on client side by level.

Comment: Have you solved the issue using Mises's recommendations?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I changed my data structure on cloud firestore to have well known collection names.

Comment: @Mises Maybe you should consider adding the information you provided as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no way to get collections names (well on client side for sure). Collections are like table name in regular databases. If you don't know what you can have in collections, and you let users create their own collections, you will end up having your database used by some hackers. This is how rules should look like in firebase.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // This line prevent anyone except server to manipulate database.
    // All other lines overwrite this rule and let do something in database for users.
    match /{document=**} { 
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // Here, users can create and update their documents, but they cannot delete them.
    // Because of rules above, they cannot create nested collection.
    // This is important because someone may do his own nested collection and use it to his project.
    match /bookings/{docId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      allow update: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      allow create: if request.auth != null
    }
    match /app/{docId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
    return request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
```

Quiz rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} { 
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /quizzes/{docId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.public == true || resource.data.owner == resuest.auth.uid
      allow update, detele: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
      allow create: if request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
    }
  }
}
```

Example query web in TypeScript:

```js
function getQuizzes() {
   const ref = collection('quizzes')
   const qRef = query(ref, ...[where("level", ">=" 1), where("public", "==", true ), where("category", "==", "math"), order("level", "asc")])
   return getDocs(qRef)
}
```

**Code might be buggy. I didn't test it.**